# Need help understanding int array to byte array method and Little/Big Endian wondering?

Tags: java, buffer, arrays, endianness, bytebuffer

Have a couple questions, first on this method, which converts an `int[]` to a `byte[]`:

```
public static byte[] intToByte(int[] input){
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(input.length * 4);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    intBuffer.put(input);
    byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
    return array;
}
```

Im making a game, and I have to send a byte array over a socket, and I like this method because it works basically, but I dont like to use anything I dont truly understand what its doing, so could you give me some insight on what this method is doing? I believe it first creates enough space for the bits, but why does it do 'times' four to the length? And is the intBuffer connected to the byteBuffer? because why do you need all the Intbuffer stuff if not.

Okay last question, whats the deal with `BIG_ENDIAN` vs. `LITTLE_ENDIAN`? For example, in my other method, which converts a byte array to int array, what is the benefits for including `.order(BIG_ENDIAN)`?

```
public static int[] byteToInt(byte[] input){
   IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
   int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
   intBuf.get(array);
   return array;
}
```

I know `BIG_ENDIAN` and `LITTLE_ENDIAN` just dictate how the bytes are ordered, but why even define an endian? why not just have this?

```
IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).asIntBuffer();
```

Answer (score 3):

IntBuffer is an int view of the byte array of byteArray. The purpose to use IntBuffer is its put(int[]) which allows to the input int array in one go. As a matter of fact you could do without IntBuffer as

```
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(input.length * 4);
    for(int i : input) {
        byteBuffer.putInt(i);
    }
...
```

the result would be the same.

This demonstrates the difference between BigEndian (default) and LittleEndian

```
        int[] input = {1,2,3,4};
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(input.length * 4);
//      byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        for(int i : input) {
            byteBuffer.putInt(i);
        }
        byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

output

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```

uncomment `byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` and the output will be

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

An `int` takes up four bytes, so you have to allocate a `byte[]` four times as long as the `int[]`.  `asIntBuffer()` returns a view of the `ByteBuffer` as an `IntBuffer`, so putting the `int[]` into the `IntBuffer` converts all the `int`s into four bytes each and puts them into the `ByteBuffer`.

Endianness defines which order the four bytes of an `int` are written into the `ByteBuffer`.

As for your last question, an `IntBuffer` is not an `int[]`, nor does an `IntBuffer` obtained from `ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer()` support the `array()` method.  In other words, there is no backing `int[]` to such an `IntBuffer`, since the implementation is based on a `byte[]`.

Comment: Im confused on your response to my last question. I know an IntBuffer is not an int[], the code all works, ive tested it all. Im just wondering why even define the order as big or little endian? why not just not include that? Im just confused on your response to my last question.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary in the second implementation, since the default byte order of a `ByteBuffer` is big endian -- but it might be useful to help clarify code for the reader.